# how to count the words in each sentence from the file (Python)

Tags: python

There is a task to count the number of words in the sentence. For example:

> ```
> sentences = "hello how are you. I am good. that's good.";
> ```

The result should be that:

> hello how are you. 4 words;
> I am good.           3 words;
> that's good.         2 words;

I found an example of a solution to my problem, but it is written in C#. I don't understand what to replace TrimEnd with in Python.

```
    var sentences = "hello how are you. I am good. that's good.";
    foreach (var sentence in sentences.TrimEnd('.').Split('.'))
        Console.WriteLine(sentence.Trim().Split(' ').Count());
```

Please help solve this problem in Python.

Comment: Look into the `split` function and what it takes as an argument.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Comment: `TrimEnd` is the same as `rstrip` in Python.  Seriously, though, YOU need to take a stab at coding this.  Don't wimp out and have us write it for you.

Answer (score 2):

Pythonic way, One liner!

```
sentences = "hello how are you. I am good. that's good.".split('.')
[print(f'{sen}. {len(sen.split())} words;',end=' ') for sen in sentences if sen]
```

**Output:**

> hello how are you. 4 words;  I am good. 3 words;  that's good. 2
> words;

Comment: Should remove the semi-colon `;` after `split();`

Comment: Okay, Please mark it as an accepted answer so others will grasp the perfect answer easily..

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
sentences = "hello how are you. I am good. that's good."

result = str()
for sentence in sentences.split(". "):
  result += str(sentence + '. {} words;'.format(len(sentence.split())))
print(result)
```

Outputs:

> hello how are you. 4 words; I am good. 3 words; that's good.. 2 words;